# LCD Monitor displaying jagged lines

Tags: display, hardware-failure

My 19-inch acer monitor is showing all vertical lines as moving and jagged lines. It's very painful on the eye. I tried capturing a screenshot but the lines in the screenshot are perfect. So I figured it must be the monitor. Anybody have a similar problem? I tried fixing the refresh rate, focus and clock on my settings. And one more thing, the settings display is smooth when I press the menu on the monitor. 'Auto' settings didn't solve the problem.

My monitor has only a VGA input.

Comment: Have you tried [degaussing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degaussing)
</joke>
......or a different monitor/video card to determine if it's the monitor or video card??

Comment: Simple thing to check: I've seen this before when the cable is not fully seated on either end. Check that if you haven't already. :)